# JXTA JXSE 2.7 with broken JBoss Netty library dependency

Tags: netty, jxta

Recently I was investigating p2p framework to use and I came across JXTA. Too bad, Oracle decided to dropped JXTA. Real shame for a nice software. Anyway the problem that I have is trying to start a node in rendezvous mode.

NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager(NetworkManager.ConfigMode.RENDEZVOUS,...);

I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError when I call manager.startNetwork();

The class it is having problem with is:
org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/httptunnel/HttpTunnelClientChannelFactory

JXSE 2.7 came with JBoss netty 3.1.5 GA jar file. And there is really no such a class in that release of Netty.

Has anyone successfully ran a JXSE rendezvous node and what should be the right Netty jar file with JXSE 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

try this jar file :http://files.cnblogs.com/cuizhf/httptunnel-0.92.rar

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can build a netty JAR with the correct set of classes in it to run JXSE 2.7:

- Download the git repository from here:
  https://github.com/iainmcgin/netty
  (I just grabbed the zip file)
- Build it using maven:

  ```
  cd iainmcgin-netty-5f5c87b (or whatever the zip file gives you)

  mvn package
  ```
- The build failed for me and I had to add the following XML to the pom.xml file, before the 
  </project> tag:

  <pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
       <id>JBoss Repo</id>
       <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
       <name>JBoss Repo</name>
     </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
- I got another fail message from maven, but it seemed to create the jar file OK in a subfolder named target.
- Final step is to make sure the jar file maven just built is in your classpath when running your JXTA programs. (the file is called netty-4.0.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar).

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone successfully ran a JXSE rendezvous node and what should be
>   the right Netty jar file with JXSE 2.7?

Yes, I sure did. The dependencies are available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicaljxta/files/). It seems to me that the dependencies may not be on your class path.