# JXTA 2.7 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/httptunnel/HttpTunnelClientChannelFactory

Tags: jxta

I apologize for the redundant question but it seems the entire web doesn't have a clear answer to this major problem. I downloaded JXTA 2.7, dependency files, netty jars and it still doesn't work.

The answer to add a jar to the classpath is an answer without an answer.
The answer of use the dependency files from sourceforge doesn't work.
The answer of we need a proper version of netty is useless unless the right version number is provided.

So, can somebody please provide a CLEAR solution to this Netty "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/httptunnel/HttpTunnelClientChannelFactory" problem?

Thank you so much for your support!!

Comment: I had the similar problem and it had nothing to do with the libraries but when i created the Network in ADHOC mode (anything other than EDGE) then it was working. So it was very confusing what to do as there were no answers. You can try this option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this error occurs during JXTA bootstrapping. I am hoping @JVerstry can answer this question of what exact version of Netty we need since he manages the JXTA releases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same problem as [JXTA JXSE 2.7 with broken JBoss Netty library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466735/jxta-jxse-2-7-with-broken-jboss-netty-library-dependency/10517354#10517354) where instructions are provided on how to build a working netty jar.